# I have Python list containing set of dictionaries, like a JSON representation. My task is to find no. of users against serial_ids.

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Input data is like below.But, it actually contains thousands of dictionaries under this list and serial_ids are repeated throughout the list.

```
[{
        "serial_id": 1,  
        "name": "ABC"
    }, 
    {
        "serial_id": 6,  
        "name": "DEF"
    }, 
    {
        "serial_id": 8,  
        "name": "GHI"
    }, 
    {
        "serial_id": 0, 
        "name": "JKL"
    }, 
    {
        "serial_id": 6,  
        "name": "VVV"
    }]
```

Now, I know the range of serial_id but I don't want to hardcode it.
My task is to find the total number of users (i.e. name_count basically) per serial id. It will be better if I can get a table like structure sorted in descending order containing columns, serial_id and user_count per serial_id.

Questions are:
Can we make use of Dataframe concept? If possible, I would like to.
I am unable to get any method to achieve the required output.

Thanks in Advance !!

Since the JSON data is pulled from an API, below is the code I tried to but failed badly.

```
#Python libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
from collections import Counter

url1 = 'INPUT URL'
#print ('Retrieving',url1)

#uh = urllib2.urlopen(url1)
r = requests.get(url1)
r = r.text
#print r
#print ('Retrieved', len(r), 'characters')

try:js = json.loads(r) # js -> Native Python list
except:js = None
#print js

info = json.dumps(js , indent =4) #Prints out the JSON data in a nice format which we call as "Pretty Print"
#print (info)

'''
#print ('User Count:' , len(info))

for item in (js):

    print ('Name' , item["name"])
'''

'''
user_count = 0

for item in (js):

    #df = {'serial_id': Series[item["affiliate_id"]]} //ERROR
     df = DataFrame({'serial_id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
     #Hard-coded the serial_id since we know the range of the affiliate_id

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use Pandas dataframes:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

jstring = StringIO("""[{
        "serial_id": 1,  
        "name": "ABC"
    }, 
    {
        "serial_id": 6,  
        "name": "DEF"
    }, 
    {
        "serial_id": 8,  
        "name": "GHI"
    }, 
    {
        "serial_id": 0, 
        "name": "JKL"
    }, 
    {
        "serial_id": 6,  
        "name": "VVV"
    }]""")

df = pd.read_json(jstring)

df_out = df.groupby('serial_id')['name'].count().reset_index(name='name_count')

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   serial_id  name_count
0          0           1
1          1           1
2          6           2
3          8           1
```